# Simple Injector and Mapster Dependency Injection setup

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector, mapster

The documentation on the [Mapster Wiki](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Dependency-Injection) isnt very good and I cant seem to get it hooked up with Simple Injector.

I have this below:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(() =>
   MapperProvider.GetConfiguredMappingConfig());
container.Register<IMapper, ServiceMapper>(Lifestyle.Singleton);

public class MapperProvider
{
    public static TypeAdapterConfig GetConfiguredMappingConfig()
    {
        var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
        return config;
    }
}
```

**Error**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type BoutsController failed. The constructor of type ServiceMapper contains the parameter with name 'serviceProvider' and type IServiceProvider, but IServiceProvider is not registered. For IServiceProvider to be resolved, it must be registered in the container.

StackTrace:

```
at SimpleInjector.InstanceProducer.VerifyExpressionBuilding()
at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt(InstanceProducer[] producersToVerify)
at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyThatAllExpressionsCanBeBuilt()
at SimpleInjector.Container.VerifyInternal(Boolean suppressLifestyleMismatchVerification)
at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()
at Tournaments.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in F:\Global.asax.cs:line 339
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Mapster, but after peeking at the `ServiceMapper` [source code](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/blob/ac8b6afe596bcb914e47a39b0d8404ef8b82080c/src/Mapster.DependencyInjection/ServiceMapper.cs), I think the following code allows you to integrate with Mapster:

```cs
var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(new ServiceMapper(container, config));
```

Comment: Is this for a singleton?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @MikeFlynn yes, it is a singleton: https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/html/M_SimpleInjector_Container_RegisterInstance.htm

Comment: Compared to MS.DI and Autofac, Simple Injector's scoping facilities is based on ambient context. This means that the `ServiceMapper` can be registered as Singleton, even though it might resolve Scoped and Transient services.